# Why is A[:,i] different from A[:][i]?

Tags: python, matrix, linear-algebra

```
A = np.array([
    [1,2,3],
    [4,5,6],
    [7,8,9]
])
print(A[:,0])
print(A[:][0])
```

output:

```
array([1, 4, 7])
array([1, 2, 3])
```

Im confused by the second output, because it should select : (everything) from the first dimension, so all row vectors. And 0 from the second dimension, the entries of the row vectors, to extract the 0th column vector.

Comment: Actually A[:] = A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comma notation `[:,0]` is from numpy and means, `all in 1st dimension` and `0 in 2nd dimension` so `A[:,0]` gives the first column

The other one is not equivalent, as `[:]` copies the full list, `A[:]` is same as `A`, then you take `0 in first dimension` so `A[:][0]` gives first row

Answer (score 2):

A[:] makes a copy of the array.

```
>>> A[:]
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
>>> (A[:] == A).all()
True
>>> A[:] is A
False
```

A[:][0] is *the-same-as* A[0]

```
>>> A[0]
array([1, 2, 3])
```

---

[Indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/1.19/user/basics.indexing.html)

Answer (score 1):

Numpy is lying to you and doing the right thing.  If all the indices are integers, then it turns out that in Numpy `foo[a,b,c]` is the same as `foo[a][b][c]`. You have Numpy to thank for this, not Python.

Internally, `foo[a,b,c]` is the same as `foo[(a,b,c)]`, so you end up calling `foo.__getitem__((a, b, c))`.  It's the Numpy `__getitem__` implementation, not some magic of subscripting, that gives you the right answer.